# Find the limit of $\{\frac{a_n}{n^2} \}$ with condition $a_{n+1}=a_n + \frac{2}{n+1}a_{n-1}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $a_0$ and $a_1$ be arbitrary real numbers, and let $a_{n+1}=a_n +
> \dfrac{2}{n+1}a_{n-1}$ $(n= 1, 2, \dots)$. Show that the sequence
>   $\left \{\dfrac{a_n}{n^2} \right \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is convergent and
>   find its limit.

Consider applying **Stolz Theorem**, we can obtain
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n}{n^2}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{(n+1)^2-n^2}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2a_{n-1}}{(2n+1)(n+1)}.$$
But how to go on with thi?

Comment: Solution on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1155017p5477236.

Comment: @MartinR I've seen that already. But is there other solution?